# C++ Value passed to function different from received value

Tags: c++, pass-by-value

I'm currently having an issue with a function call of get_set() for a doubly-linked list class I am making. The function returns a vector of all the elements within the list from position_from to position_to. For the tests, I am sending

`dll_UT->get_set( dll_UT->size()/2+1 , dll_UT->size()-1)`

however, the value of `dll_UT->size()` somehow doubles within the call. When called directly before the function call, it shows the correct value of 100 (half the size of the list), but when inside the function this turns to 200. I've left console logs below as well as screenshots of the test.cpp and doubly_linked_list.cpp.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated as I've never seen this type of behavior before and would like to understand why such a thing is occuring.

get_set function: (works as intended)

```
std::vector<int> Doubly_linked_list::get_set(unsigned position_from, unsigned position_to){

     std::cout << "\nthis->size() = " << this->size() << "\nthis->size()/2+1 = " << this->size()/2+1 << std::endl;
     std::cout << "\nposition_from = " << position_from << "\nposition_to = " << position_to << std::endl;

     std::vector<int> temp;
     temp.reserve(position_to - position_from);

     while(position_from < position_to){
          temp.pushback( this->get_data( position_from );
          position_from++;
     }

     temp.push_back( this->get_data( position_to ));

     return temp;
```

For  below, `expected_set` is already filled out and is used to compare to `dll_UT` (the doubly linked list). True size of expected_set & dll_UT is 200.

Test file which produces the error:

```
std::cout << "\nTEST.cpp::: dll_UT->size() = " << dll_UT->size() <<
               "TEST.cpp::: dll_UT->size()/2+1 = " << dll_UT->size()/2+1 << std::endl;

ASSERT_EQ(std::vector<int> ( expected_set.begin()+expected_set.size()/2+1 , expected_set.end()),
                             dll_UT->get_set( dll_UT->size()/2+1, dll_UT->size()-1));
```

When looking at the console log below, we can see that before the function call get_set

`dll_UT->size() = 200` , and that `dll_UT->size()/2+1 = 100`

however, once passed to the function, instead of the expected value of `position_from == 100`, postion_from doubles and now `position_from == 200` i.e **The Value passed into the function was not the same value the function recieved.**

I've attached a console log below to show this behavior.

Any help on this issue is greatly appreciated as I've never seen this behavior before in C++ and would like to know what is causing it.

[Console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTyyO.png)

Minimal Reproduceable Example Code:

For dll.h:

```
#include "node.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

namespace lab6{
    class doubly_linked_list{
        lab6::node *head;
        lab6::node *tail;
    public:
        doubly_linked_list();
        doubly_linked_list(int input);
        doubly_linked_list(std::vector<int> vector_input);
        doubly_linked_list(const doubly_linked_list &original);
        ~doubly_linked_list();

        int get_data(unsigned position);
        std::vector<int> get_set(unsigned position_from, unsigned position_to);

        unsigned size();
        bool is_empty();

        void append(int input);
     };
}
```

For Node.h:

```
namespace lab6{
    class node{
        int data;
    public:
        node* next;
        node* prev;
        
        explicit node(int input_data) : data(input_data), next(nullptr), prev(nullptr){};
        int get_data(){return data;};
    };
}
```

For Dll.cpp:

```
#include "../inc/doubly_linked_list.h"

namespace lab6{
    doubly_linked_list::doubly_linked_list() {
        head = nullptr;
        tail = nullptr;
    }

    doubly_linked_list::~doubly_linked_list() {

        node* current = head;

        while(head != nullptr){
            head = head->next;

            delete current;

            current = head;
        }
        
    }

   int doubly_linked_list::get_data(unsigned position) {
        
        lab6::node *iter = head;
        for(int i = 0; i < position; i++)
            iter = iter->next;   // {3} = [H] ->> [ ] ->> [ ] ->> Null

        return iter->get_data();
    }

    std::vector<int> doubly_linked_list::get_set(unsigned position_from, unsigned position_to) {

        std::cout << "\n\t__NEW TEST__\nSize of size/2+1 = " << this->size()/2+1 << "\nSize of size()-1 = " << this->size()-1 << std::endl;
        std::cout << "position_from pre-loop = " << position_from << "\nposition_to pre-loop= " << position_to << std::endl;
        
        std::vector<int> temp;
        temp.reserve(position_to - position_from);

        while(position_from < position_to){
            temp.push_back( this->get_data(position_from) );
            position_from++;
        }
        
        temp.push_back(this->get_data(position_to));
      
        std::cout << "Size of position_from post-loop= " << position_from << "\nSize of position_to post-loop= " << position_to << "\n\t__END TEST__" << std::endl;

        return temp;
    }

    unsigned doubly_linked_list::size() {

        node* iter = head;
        unsigned count;

        while(iter){
            count++;
            iter = iter->next;
        }

        return count;
    }

     bool doubly_linked_list::is_empty() {

        if(head == nullptr)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    void doubly_linked_list::append(int input) {

        node* new_node = new node(input);

        if(head == nullptr){
            head = new_node;
            tail = new_node;
            return;
        }

        tail->next = new_node;
        new_node->prev = tail;
        tail = new_node;

    }
}
```

For Test File:

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "doubly_linked_list.h"
#include <algorithm>

class Lab06Fixture : public ::testing::Test {

protected:
    virtual void SetUp() {
        dll_UT = new lab6::doubly_linked_list();
    }

    virtual void TearDown() {
        delete dll_UT;
    }

public:
    lab6::doubly_linked_list * dll_UT;
};


TEST(Lab06crsh, crash_test_dll) {
    std::vector <int> number_list;
    lab6::doubly_linked_list *list;

    for(int i=0; i < 20; i++){
        number_list.push_back(i);
    }

    list = new lab6::doubly_linked_list();
    std::cout << "Now Deleting list 1 " << std::endl;
    delete list;
    list = new lab6::doubly_linked_list(73);
    std::cout << "Now Deleting list 2 " << std::endl;
    delete list;
    std::cout << "Running vector input" << std::endl;
    list = new lab6::doubly_linked_list(number_list);
}


TEST_F(Lab06Fixture, append_get_data_get_set_test) {
    std::vector <int> expected_set;
    EXPECT_TRUE(dll_UT->is_empty());
    for (int i = 1; i < 200; ++i) {
        dll_UT->append(i);
        ASSERT_EQ(i,dll_UT->size());
        expected_set.push_back(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
            ASSERT_EQ(expected_set[j],dll_UT->get_data(j)) << "Iteration: i= " << i << " j= " << j;
        }
    }

    ASSERT_EQ(expected_set, dll_UT->get_set(0,dll_UT->size()-1));
    ASSERT_EQ(std::vector<int>(expected_set.begin(),expected_set.begin()+expected_set.size()/2), dll_UT->get_set(0,dll_UT->size()/2-1));//first half of data

    std::cout << "\nTEST.cpp::: dll_UT-size() = " << dll_UT->size() << 
    "\nTEST.cpp::: dll_UT-size()/2+1 = " << dll_UT->size()/2+1 << std::endl;

    std::cout << "\nTEST.cpp::: expected_set.size() = " << expected_set.size() << 
    "\nTEST.cpp::: expected_set.begin()+expected_set.size()/2+1 = " << expected_set.size()/2+1 << std::endl;

    ASSERT_EQ(std::vector<int> (expected_set.begin()+expected_set.size()/2+1,expected_set.end()), 
                                dll_UT->get_set( dll_UT->size()/4+1 , dll_UT->size()-1));//second half of data
}
```

Comment: We'll need a [mcve].

Comment: Updated post to include minimal reproduction.  ☺

Comment: In your size function you never give count an initial value so you end up with a completely random value.  You need to initialize count as zero before the loop.

Comment: By the way, you MVCE doesn't compile because you are missing the contructors for doubly_linked_list that take an integer and that take a vector (the default constructor is the only one)

Comment: After I made your code compile and I passed `-O3 -Wall -Wextra` as compile options, the compiler said `warning: 'count' may be used uninitialized in this function` so the compiler can warn you about these things.  I like to pass `-O3 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -pedantic-errors -fsanitize=address,undefined` as compile options because that finds a lot of bad things.

Comment: Also, it helps if you test as you go - that way you write a function and you test it right then so you know where you have gone wrong right away when it doesn't work.